# CoffeeScript Class argument set grammar

Tags: coffeescript

I'm currently working on CoffeeScript and I got a question that how to write the code below in smart way.

```
class TestClass
    constructor : (name) ->
        @name = name if name?
    name : "Jack"
    sayHi : ->
        console.log "Hi #{@name}"
```

I know `constructor : (@name) ->` is available to set the argument as instance property though,It doesn't work if I want to use class property instead  when the argument is missing.
`constructor : (@name) ->` declare this.name even if the argument is null

```
class TestClass
    constructor : (@name) ->
    name : "Jack"
    sayHi : ->
        console.log "Hi #{@name}"

foo = new TestClass()
foo.sayHi()
# "hi undefined" because foo.name exists with null value.
```

Of course I've already tried `constructor : (@name?) ->` but this would trigger a syntax error.

Is there any better way or I have to write the code `@name = name if name?` and is the best way so far?

thanks for your help

Comment: So you want to be able to do `t = new TestClass; TestClass::name = 'pancakes'` and have `t.name == 'pancakes'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using [default value](http://coffeescript.org/#literals) for `constructor` argument?

```
class TestClass
  constructor: (@name = "Jack") ->
```

Comment: This. IMHO, leave the defaults off the prototype.

Comment: then It's not class property anymore.which means I have to change all instances property when I want to change value of `name` and there is no way to make sure `name` of instances property is generated by default value or was set according to the argument.(`new TestClass("Jack")` or `new TestClass()`)

Comment: @suish I think, you should stuck with your current solution then.

Comment: Though, I can't see advantages of changing prototype of an existing class. Prototype mutations usually lead to errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
class TestClass
    _name = "Jack"
    constructor : (@name = _name) ->

tc = new TestClass
console.log tc

tc = new TestClass("Paul")
console.log tc
```

Producing:

```
{ name: 'Jack' }
{ name: 'Paul' }
```

Comment: I am not asking how to set default value of instance property.
like I said, I want it to be Class property not instance property.
`constructor : (name) -> @name = name if name?` and use TestClass.name if produced instance does not have name property and `constructor : (@name = _name) ->` setting default value if constructor does not get the argument are totally different thing because when you do neither `delete tc.name` or changing name property of TestClass after declaring `tc` they works differently.